# iOS 12.2 MPMusicPlayerController reporting incorrect playback state

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, notificationcenter, swift5

MPMusicPlayerController is reporting playback state as paused when a song reaches the end, and is also reporting playback state as paused after queueing a song, even after an explicit call to `.Stop()`.

This behaviour didn't exist prior, and is now causing issues for my queueing code which is using a check for `playbackState == .stopped`.

I have setup a notification center handler for `MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChange` which calls a function that tests if the playback state is `.stopped` which in turn calls a delegate function to alert other aspects of my app (transport state, removing the song from the app's queue, queueing the subsequent track, etc.) that the song has completed.

This behaviour was fine prior to this update.

Can anybody enlighten me to a release note explaining the change, or provide guidance on how to properly detect the end of a song?

I have tried comparing the current playback position to the song's duration, but they never seem to line up. The current playback position always seems to be a couple of seconds shorter than the duration. I've tried comparing TimeIntervals (too high a resolution) as well as using a formatter to convert them to a string and comparing that (seeing as the times are reported correctly in the UI).

I should also mention I have tried testing against `nowPlayingItem` being nil, but the current track is not removed (also part of the problem, but I'm treating them as related at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why the behaviour has changed, i could'nt find anything in the patch notes. However you should be able to queue the current song and the next one using `setQueueWithItemCollection`, and use the `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange` event to update the queue, instead of setting one song at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I manually manage the queue so that when a song finishes playing, it doesn't automatically start playing the next song. I'm already listening to NowPlayingItemDidChange for the reason you state, but it's not being fired either.